# How can I convert text in a cell to a sequence of ascii code values with a separator in Excel 2016 or LibreOffice?

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, ascii, libreoffice-calc

Given a cell with text, I need a formula that will output the sequence of ascii codes for each char in that text string.

- the input string can be assumed to have chars with ascii values within the 0-255 range
- the input string is typically 4 characters or less but may be up to 10
- the output should include a separator, e.g. space (" ")
- ideally, the output should not end with the separator
- the formula must work in Excel 2016 or LibreOffice (my online access is limited)

Examples (with space as separator: input -> output

- abc -> 97 98 99
- YZ[ -> 89 90 91
- T -> 84

The closest code examples I could find was [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sum-ascii-values-of-letters/667214dc-310c-460a-a684-04e8fc2a3e72)
:

- `=SUM(CODE(MID(C1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(C1))),1)))` which uses Array Formulas
- `=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))` which avoids Array Formulas

In both cases above, I was unable to adapt the examples to use CONCATENATE to join the pieces into an Ascii code sequence.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld's first solution works in Google Sheets. Even though it is on online-only solution, it does bypass the need for Office 365 and allows for batch processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Excel 2016`, a formula-based solution will only be feasible for strings containing no more than 5 characters, viz:

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(10^(15-3*(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))-1))*CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1))),REPT(" 000",6))," 00"," ")," 0"," "))`

Otherwise, you'll require `VBA`.

Comment: This solution works for 95% of my cases. Can you update the solution to check if the string length is greater than 5 and if so join to or more of these formulas? Out of curiosity, what determines the limit?

Comment: The limit on the number of characters is 5 since the ASCII code for each character can be a numeric with up to 3 digits, and we need to generate a large numeric whose digits comprise the combined digits from those ASCII codes. 5x3=15, which is the limit on the floating-point precision for positive numerics in Excel.

Comment: For anyone else needing to work strings longer than 5 chars, the following is a workaround that works for string lengths up to 10 and can be extended (to the formula string limit):
=CONCATENATE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(10^(15-3*(ROW(INDEX(C:C,1):INDEX(C:C,LEN(C2)))-1))*CODE(MID(C2,ROW(INDEX(C:C,1):INDEX(C:C,LEN(C2))),1))),REPT(" 000",6))," 00"," ")," 0"," ")),IF(LEN(C2)>5," "&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(10^(15-3*(ROW(INDEX(C:C,1):INDEX(C:C,LEN(C2)-5))-1))*CODE(MID(C2,ROW(INDEX(C:C,6):INDEX(C:C,LEN(C2))),1))),REPT(" 000",6))," 00"," ")," 0"," ")),""))

Answer (score 4):

If you have Office 365:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))
```

or
`= ARRAYTOTEXT(CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),0)`

Comment: I did come across those solutions using Office 365, but do not have it. I have now updated the original post to make that clear. Thanks. And thanks for the solution using Office 365. Hopefully someone else will benefit from it.

Comment: Your first solution worked in Google Sheets! It's not an offline solution for Excel 2016 but let me move forward a step in a larger problem. 

Comment: Added LibreOffice as alternative tool for solution.